# Having trouble storing and retrieving data with Java/sql

Tags: java, sql

I am fairly new to Java and I'm not very familiar with sql either. I am working on a program that takes flooring orders and stores them in an SQL database. The names and addresses will store just fine but the rest of the information won't. The information retrieval isn't working either. I'm not certain what I am doing wrong either. I removed the information from the Connection object for obvious reasons, but I can assure you that this has the correct information in my program.. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FlooringOrders extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JLabel lblFloorType, lblRoomSize, lblLength, lblWidth, lblName, 
lblAddress, lblOrderInfo, lblTotal;
private JRadioButton rbtnWood, rbtnCarpet;
private JButton btnCalculate, btnSubmit, btnOrders;
private ButtonGroup grpType;
private JTabbedPane tab;
private JTextField txtLength, txtWidth, txtArea, txtName, txtAddress;
private JTextArea txtOrderInfo, txtTotal, txtCustomer;
private JPanel p1, p2, p3, p4;
private double Length, Width, Area, Total;
private String sLength, sWidth, sArea, sTotal, fType, insertQuery;
private PreparedStatement myQuery;
private ResultSet rs;
private DecimalFormat df;

public FlooringOrders() {

    super("Flooring Orders");

    df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.00");

    tab = new JTabbedPane();
    p1 = new JPanel();
    p2 = new JPanel();
    p3 = new JPanel();
    p4 = new JPanel();

    lblFloorType = new JLabel("Choose Floor Type: ");
    lblRoomSize = new JLabel("Enter Room Size: ");
    lblLength = new JLabel("Length (ft): ");
    lblWidth = new JLabel("Width (ft): ");
    lblName = new JLabel("Enter Name: ");
    lblAddress = new JLabel("Enter Address: ");
    lblOrderInfo = new JLabel("Order Info: ");
    lblTotal = new JLabel("Total: ");

    rbtnWood = new JRadioButton("Wood - $20/sq. ft.");
    rbtnCarpet = new JRadioButton("Carpet - $10/sq. ft.");
    grpType = new ButtonGroup();

    btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate Area");
    btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    btnOrders = new JButton("Customer Orders");

    txtLength = new JTextField(10);
    txtWidth = new JTextField(10);
    txtArea = new JTextField(10);
    txtName = new JTextField(10);
    txtAddress = new JTextField(10);

    txtOrderInfo = new JTextArea(15, 15);
    txtTotal = new JTextArea(15, 15);
    txtCustomer = new JTextArea(15, 15);

    grpType.add(rbtnCarpet);
    grpType.add(rbtnWood);

    getContentPane().add(tab);

    p1.add(lblFloorType);
    p1.add(rbtnWood);
    p1.add(rbtnCarpet);
    p1.add(lblRoomSize);
    p1.add(lblLength);
    p1.add(txtLength);
    p1.add(lblWidth);
    p1.add(txtWidth);
    p1.add(btnCalculate);
    p1.add(txtArea);
    tab.add("Flooring", p1);

    p2.add(lblName);
    p2.add(txtName);
    p2.add(lblAddress);
    p2.add(txtAddress);
    p2.add(btnSubmit);
    tab.add("Customer Info", p2);

    p3.add(lblOrderInfo);
    p3.add(txtOrderInfo);
    p3.add(lblTotal);
    p3.add(txtTotal);
    tab.add("Total", p3);

    p4.add(btnOrders);
    p4.add(txtCustomer);
    tab.add("Order List", p4);

    btnCalculate.addActionListener(this);
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(this);
    btnOrders.addActionListener(this);

} //end constructor

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {

    sLength = txtLength.getText();
    sWidth = txtWidth.getText();
    fType = "";

    Length = Double.parseDouble(sLength);
    Width = Double.parseDouble(sWidth);
    Area = 0;
    Total = 0;  

    if(a.getSource().equals(btnCalculate)) {

        Area = Length * Width;          

        if(rbtnWood.isSelected()) {

            Total = Area * 20;
            fType.equals("Wood");

        } else if(rbtnCarpet.isSelected()) {

            Total = Area * 10;
            fType.equals("Carpet");

        } //end if/else

        sArea = String.valueOf(df.format(Area));
        sTotal = String.valueOf(df.format(Total));

        txtArea.setText(sArea);
        txtTotal.setText(sTotal);

        System.out.println("Calculate Area pressed");

    } //end if

    if(a.getSource().equals(btnSubmit)) {

        newOrder();

        System.out.println("Submit pressed");

    } //end if

    if(a.getSource().equals(btnOrders)) {

        orderList();

        System.out.println("Customer Orders pressed");

    } //end if

} //end actionPerformed

public void newOrder() {

    insertQuery = "INSERT into CustomerOrders(CustomerName, CustomerAddress,
FloorType, RoomSize, Total) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    try {

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection();

        myQuery = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);           


        myQuery.setString(1, txtName.getText());            
        myQuery.setString(2, txtAddress.getText());
        myQuery.setString(3, fType);
        myQuery.setDouble(4, Area);
        myQuery.setDouble(5, Total);

        myQuery.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for your order!");   

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    } //end try/catch

} //end newOrder

public void orderList() {

try {

    rs = myQuery.executeQuery("SELECT * from CustomerOrders");
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = md.getColumnCount();

        while (rs.next()) {

            for(int i = 1; i < columns; i++) {

                txtCustomer.setText(rs.getString(i) + " ");

                System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + " ");

                System.out.println();

            } //end for

        }// end while

} catch (SQLException e) {

    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();

}   //end try/catch

} //end orderList

} //end class
```

Comment: Since you are new, a request instead of a close flag: Can you reduce your code to the issue only, and can you add some line breaks in you code so that we don't have to scroll right to read the relevant lines?

Comment: Please try to post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE]. So take your time and limit your example by removing unnecessary things like GUI since simple console should be enough (unless you are sure that problem is related with GUI). Also if it is possible try to describe problem you are facing in more detail. What you expect to happen and what is happening instead (do you get error/exception/incorrect result - what would be correct result and why would you expect it).

Comment: Ok, I edited out the GUI components. Sorry, this is only my second time posting to this forum.

Comment: @Karlnage What problem do you face with your code?

Comment: Your code still depends on GUI which prevents us from reusing it. Try to create simple but complete example which will allow us (and future readers) to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about, Pshemo. I added the whole code and that wasn't good enough, I edited to just the action coding and that wasn't enough. What are you talking about? How can I post a complete code but edit stuff out? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also don't use `code-snippet` but `code-sample` (`{}` button in editor or `Ctrl+K` shortcut on keyboard). `code-snippet`s are meant to be used with code which actually can be run by browser like HTML/JavaScript (it is not same as Java).

Comment: I am talking about code example which we can simply copy and paste to your computers and run it without adding anything.

Comment: You can simply create one class with main method in which you will do all things you are doing with GUI which connecting to DB and modifying its content. You can print results to console using simple `System.out.println`.

Comment: @Beniton The code is supposed to save a customer's order to an sql database. It is supposed to store a name, address, floor type, floor area, and a total. The name and address will store just fine but the other information won't take. Also when I press the button to display the order information from the database, it only displays a single number, 0.0.

Comment: @Karlnage I think you are reusing the preparedStatement.  You can close it and create new Statement when try to list orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **public void orderList() {** you should create a statement before executing it.

```
 myQuery = conn.createStatement( );
 rs = myQuery.executeQuery("SELECT * from CustomerOrders");
```

Let me know if it helps you.

I have refactored you code a little bit. Hope it should help you progress.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class FlooringOrders extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JLabel lblFloorType, lblRoomSize, lblLength, lblWidth, lblName,
            lblAddress, lblOrderInfo, lblTotal;
    private JRadioButton rbtnWood, rbtnCarpet;
    private JButton btnCalculate, btnSubmit, btnOrders;
    private ButtonGroup grpType;
    private JTabbedPane tab;
    private JTextField txtLength, txtWidth, txtArea, txtName, txtAddress;
    private JTextArea txtOrderInfo, txtTotal, txtCustomer;
    private JPanel p1, p2, p3, p4;
    private double Length, Width, Area, Total;
    private String sLength, sWidth, sArea, sTotal, fType, insertQuery;
    private PreparedStatement myQuery;
    private ResultSet rs;
    private DecimalFormat df;

    public FlooringOrders() {

        super("Flooring Orders");

        df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.00");

        tab = new JTabbedPane();
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p2 = new JPanel();
        p3 = new JPanel();
        p4 = new JPanel();

        lblFloorType = new JLabel("Choose Floor Type: ");
        lblRoomSize = new JLabel("Enter Room Size: ");
        lblLength = new JLabel("Length (ft): ");
        lblWidth = new JLabel("Width (ft): ");
        lblName = new JLabel("Enter Name: ");
        lblAddress = new JLabel("Enter Address: ");
        lblOrderInfo = new JLabel("Order Info: ");
        lblTotal = new JLabel("Total: ");

        rbtnWood = new JRadioButton("Wood - $20/sq. ft.");
        rbtnCarpet = new JRadioButton("Carpet - $10/sq. ft.");
        grpType = new ButtonGroup();

        btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate Area");
        btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        btnOrders = new JButton("Customer Orders");

        txtLength = new JTextField(10);
        txtWidth = new JTextField(10);
        txtArea = new JTextField(10);
        txtName = new JTextField(10);
        txtAddress = new JTextField(10);

        txtOrderInfo = new JTextArea(15, 15);
        txtTotal = new JTextArea(15, 15);
        txtCustomer = new JTextArea(15, 15);

        grpType.add(rbtnCarpet);
        grpType.add(rbtnWood);

        getContentPane().add(tab);

        p1.add(lblFloorType);
        p1.add(rbtnWood);
        p1.add(rbtnCarpet);
        p1.add(lblRoomSize);
        p1.add(lblLength);
        p1.add(txtLength);
        p1.add(lblWidth);
        p1.add(txtWidth);
        p1.add(btnCalculate);
        p1.add(txtArea);
        tab.add("Flooring", p1);

        p2.add(lblName);
        p2.add(txtName);
        p2.add(lblAddress);
        p2.add(txtAddress);
        p2.add(btnSubmit);
        tab.add("Customer Info", p2);

        p3.add(lblOrderInfo);
        p3.add(txtOrderInfo);
        p3.add(lblTotal);
        p3.add(txtTotal);
        tab.add("Total", p3);

        p4.add(btnOrders);
        p4.add(txtCustomer);
        tab.add("Order List", p4);

        btnCalculate.addActionListener(this);
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(this);
        btnOrders.addActionListener(this);

    } // end constructor

    private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection("");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        if (a.getSource().equals(btnCalculate)) {
            sLength = txtLength.getText();
            sWidth = txtWidth.getText();
            fType = "";
            Length = sLength.isEmpty() ? 0.0 : Double.parseDouble(sLength);
            Width = sWidth.isEmpty() ? 0.0 : Double.parseDouble(sWidth);
            Area = 0;
            Total = 0;
            Area = Length * Width;
            if (rbtnWood.isSelected()) {

                Total = Area * 20;
                fType.equals("Wood");

            } else if (rbtnCarpet.isSelected()) {

                Total = Area * 10;
                fType.equals("Carpet");

            } // end if/else

            sArea = String.valueOf(df.format(Area));
            sTotal = String.valueOf(df.format(Total));
            txtArea.setText(sArea);
            txtTotal.setText(sTotal);

            System.out.println("Calculate Area pressed");

        } // end if

        if (a.getSource().equals(btnSubmit)) {

            newOrder();

            System.out.println("Submit pressed");

        } // end if

        if (a.getSource().equals(btnOrders)) {

            orderList();

            System.out.println("Customer Orders pressed");

        } // end if

    } // end actionPerformed

    public void newOrder() {
        insertQuery = "INSERT into CustomerOrders(CustomerName, CustomerAddress,FloorType, RoomSize, Total) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("");
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
            ps.setString(1, txtName.getText());
            ps.setString(2, txtAddress.getText());
            ps.setString(3, fType);
            ps.setDouble(4, Area);
            ps.setDouble(5, Total);
            ps.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for your order!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ps != null) {
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    } // end newOrder

    public void orderList() {
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = getConnection().createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from CustomerOrders");
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = md.getColumnCount();
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i < columns; i++) {
                    txtCustomer.setText(rs.getString(i) + " ");
                    System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + " ");
                    System.out.println();

                } // end for

            }// end while
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stmt != null) {
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } // end orderList

} // end class
```

Comment: @Karlnage Did you check?

Comment: I am getting a bunch of exception errors in the console.

Comment: @Karlnage Can you post the exceptions. I can help you.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at FlooringOrders.actionPerformed(FlooringOrders.java:113)

Comment: at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)

Comment: @Karlnage sLength = txtLength.getText(); // should be length of the text or the text entered should be valid number
    sWidth = txtWidth.getText(); // same as above comment
    fType = "";

    Length = Double.parseDouble(sLength);
    Width = Double.parseDouble(sWidth);

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not certain why these variables are even a factor when this button is only supposed to retrieve and display information from the database. Those variables are used in calculating the area of the room.

Comment: But should those code get moved after the `if(a.getSource().equals(btnCalculate)) {`

Comment: @Karlnage Can you try the above code and let me know? Use may need to refactor code to use proper connection url.

Comment: This helped with the storing the area and the total variables as well as with the output part. I thank you very much for this. However, the ftype variable is still not being stored in the database. It's strange.

Comment: @Karlnage That's great. I hope you will accept my answer ;-)

Comment: Yes, Thank you! You have been a tremendous help. I'll mess around and try to figure out the ftype thing. Sorry it took so long to reply. I got married on Thursday and am actually on my honeymoon currently. I've been working on this here and there when I get a moment.

Comment: @Karlnage Hey Congrats.